# Splitting a large hex number into a list of 32 bit numbers in TCL

Tags: hex, tcl

How do you split a large hexadecimal number, say 0x111111112222222233333333, into a list of 32 bit numbers (0x11111111 0x22222222 0x33333333) using tcl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic in Tcl is based on the idea that you're dealing with numbers of arbitrary length (the implementation uses various internal representations, but you're supposed to not know too much about that). That means that we do the conversion arithmetically. Also, it helps to extract the numbers in reverse order, and if we know that the number is unsigned.

```
proc extractIntegers {number {bits 32}} {
    set accumulator {}
    set mask [expr {(1 << $bits) - 1}]
    while {$number != 0} {
        set value [expr {$number & $mask}]
        set number [expr {$number >> $bits}]
        lappend accumulator [format "%#x" $value]
    }
    return [lreverse $accumulator]
}

puts [extractIntegers 0x111111112222222233333333]
```

Comment: Extending this to handle negative numbers (which _theoretically_ have an infinite number of bits in this representation) is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the "infinite bits" case noted by Donal, we could make the proc recursive. At least then, the interpreter will eventually reach its max recursive depth and error out.

```
proc extractIntegersRecursive {number {bits 32} {mask 0}} { 
    if {$number == 0} return 
    if {$bits <= 0} {error "invalid bits"} 
    set mask [expr {$mask ? $mask : (1 << $bits) - 1}] 
    set procname [lindex [info level 0] 0] 
    return [concat \ 
        [$procname [expr {$number >> $bits}] $bits $mask] \ 
        [format %#x [expr {$number & $mask}]] \ 
    ] 
}
```